# How to distinguish NotFound returned from server and NotFound because of bad connectivity?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

On Windows Phone, I can get `WebException` with `StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound` if

1. Server returned 404
2. Server cannot be found because of bad connectivity.

On Windows Phone `WebException`'s status is `WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError` for both cases.

How can I tell case `1` from case `2`?

What I observe is when connectivity is bad (server not found) `ResponseUri` is null and `WebResponse`'s Headers contains `0` items.

**EDIT**

`ResponseUri` is not null, but rather has its `OriginalString` empty

Is it safe to do this:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Response.StatusCode)
    {
        ...
        case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            if (ex.Response.ResponseUri == null
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpWebResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString))
                DoServerNotFound();
            else
                DoServerReturned404();
```

Comment: It seems to the the way. Also, you can check it using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx

Comment: It is not 100% safe to check GetIsNetworkAvailable in bad network conditions. When network request failed, network may be missing, when I handle WebException, network may be up already

Comment: Moreover, we do check GetIsNetworkAvailable to be true before doing a web request :)

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/752898/webexception-status-propery-unreliable-in-wp7 hope, they fixed it in WP8. So, I think you have to check the ResponsUri :(

Comment: For Http, wouldn't casting the response to `HttpWebResponse` give you a `StatusCode` 404 (or 503 etc) depending on server error?  Also, matching the request object with response object seems like a good idea to get even more info about what's going on.

Comment: 404 status code can be returned by server or by a framework if a server was not found

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` to see if there is an active network connection before you make the web call. Otherwise, you end up waiting for nothing and waste a call. If there is a connection and the call still fails, you know that it is an issue with the web service.

I use that in my apps, if there is no connectivity, I don't bother making a call.

Thanks

Max

Comment: Please see my comments above. We check that too, but connection may fall somewhere in between

Answer (score 0):

If you got 'Not found' exception coz of bed request this will helps.

```
  catch (WebException ex)
       {                     
         using (WebResponse webResponse = ex.Response)
              {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse;
                using (Stream data = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                    {
                      string string = reader.ReadToEnd();

                      }
              }
          }
```